# Why is my google cloud run service inactive if requests not made in the last 24 hrs?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, microservices, serverless, google-cloud-run

I have a google cloud run microservice written in java spring boot. If the service remains inactive for around 24 hrs, and then a request comes after that time period, the service takes too much time to respond to the first request. All subsequent requests run smoothly. Checking logs on cloud run only tells me that the spring-boot server was started to handle the request. Why did it have to start again? Why was it not constantly listening like a normal backend server would?
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-8 as builder
# Set the working directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/mymaven
COPY ./ /usr/src/mymaven
RUN [ "mvn" , "clean" , "install" ]

FROM openjdk:8
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/mymaven/target /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD ["java", "-jar" , "Backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since (fully managed) Cloud Run is a serverless platform where you aren't billed when requests aren't actively running, it is optimized for [actively serving requests](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling#idle-instance).  As such, it will idle/stop instances that aren't actively being used.  Therefore, you need to build your service to [start quickly](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#starting_services_quickly) (or be tolerant of more latency for the cold-start requests) if it isn't going to be frequently accessed.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I was under the wrong assumption that it has one container minimum which is active. Unfortunately, my spring-boot app takes 10 seconds to launch in the container. Which leads to a cold start time of 10-15 seconds. How can I minimize this? The internet suggested I move away from java but I would prefer some java centric solution to tackle this issue.

Comment: By default Cloud Run scales to zero, but you can change the minimum number of instances with [`--min-instances`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--min-instances) (although note that this will have an effect on the cost of your service)

Comment: @DustinIngram you are correct, but only if you are deployed on Cloud Run for Anthos, not the fully managed Cloud Run.  There is a note a few paragraphs up from where you linked that says: "Only applicable if connecting to Cloud Run for Anthos...." referring to this and a few other flags.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear to me which you were using. it's only available in private alpha right now for the managed runtime. Email me at `dustiningram@google.com` if you'd like access.

Comment: In fairness, @GokuAfrica didn't specify which they were using, though I did assume for this answer that they were using the managed version.